# AWS ECS Not Loading Over Public IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

I've seen similar questions but none of them have an answer.

I have a docker container in AWS ECR + ECS. The connection times out. `The server at ... is taking too long to respond.` The docker file is very concise and exposes port 8000:

```
FROM python:3.10.4-alpine3.15

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /app

RUN apk update \
    && apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev postgresql-dev python3-dev libffi-dev \
    && pip install --upgrade pip

COPY ./requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY ./ ./
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

It works locally. And Amazon Cloudwatch tells me the server in the container is running.

```
...
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
```

In my task definition, I map the port 8000:

```
        "portMappings": [
            {
                "name": "django-8000-tcp",
                "containerPort": 8000,
                "hostPort": 8000,
                "protocol": "tcp",
                "appProtocol": "http"
            }
        ],
```

I have done everything in [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ECS_AWSCLI_Fargate.html#ECS_AWSCLI_Fargate_create_cluster) AWS official tutorial and have reviewed many others. I don't know what else to try or to check. Please help.

Comment: Do you have a security group attached to it? If so have you checked the rules? Also, is it in a subnet that has an internet gateway attached to it (aka public subnet)?

Comment: Thanks @LawrenceAiello. Indeed, it was the security group configuration.